# error: cannot find symbol import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;

Tags: android, build.gradle

i have following error while migrating app to SDK - 28 
error: cannot find symbol import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;

appcompat : 27.1.1
target 28
compile 28
sdk 28.0.3
This is my build.gradle file i'm not able find the problem it is throwing an error cannot find symbol import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat; and any one explain why it is throwing Thank's in advance

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '******'
            keyPassword '*********'
            storeFile file('********')
            storePassword '********'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    dexOptions {
        //jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tekis.health"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 24
        versionName '2018/02'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
           'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':MaterialEditTextlibrary')
    implementation project(':Spinnerlibrary')
    implementation project(':material')
    implementation project(':arcmenulibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
    implementation  'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation project(':payUMoneysdk')
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    //compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.7'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.7'
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please show your gradle file.

Comment: Hi@Tommy i added gradle file could you check it please.

Comment: post error log.

Comment: Hi Mr @KishoreJethava please check the following error   error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
                                ^
  symbol:   class ListViewCompat
  location: package android.support.v7.widget

Comment: yes i updated to appcompat-v7:28.0.0' still it is throwing same error

Comment: @siddamsettisrinivasarao check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `implementation  'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'` which has `v4` `ListViewCompat` and not the `v7` campatible class.

Use this one

> import android.support.v4.widget.ListViewCompat

**After comment**

If you want extent than It's not possible with `com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0` instead, remove that dependency.

`ListViewCompat` is available as non-final class in `appcompat-v7:26.1.0`

change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

to

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
```

and import `android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat`

Comment: Thank you Mr @KishoreJethava after i updated v7 to v4 it is throwing new error error: cannot inherit from final ListViewCompat
public class ListView extends ListViewCompat implements ThemeManager.OnThemeChangedListener{
                              ^

Comment: Did you find any solution?